# Swiper API Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

Hi guys I am a newbie in jquery especially when I have to work third party plugins

So I have been working with one here http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php

in one of my slides, I have a form where user submits and returns a result (php)

however it goes back to first slide after refresh, I need to direct it to last slide enabling my user to see their result. Is this possible?

This is what I have so far

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{


   }
 });  
};

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the index number of the last slide? You can set the starting slide with the option initialSlide (it's mentioned in the docs).

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
  initialSlide: 2 // set "2" to the index of the last slide
});
```

Otherwise you could get the active index with mySwiper.activeIndex before submitting the form.

Comment: Yes i do, its 3 but still doesnt work                                       <script>
window.onload = function(){
    
 var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
  initialSlide: 3 // set "2" to the index of the last slide
});  }

</script>

Comment: I forked an existing fiddle, where you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/nDKX9/ Could you provide a fiddle with more informations, e.g. your swiper html-code?

Comment: Thank you, I can see its working on fiddle, but this is what i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined idangerous.swiper-2.1.min.js:68
a.createPagination idangerous.swiper-2.1.min.js:68
Swiper idangerous.swiper-2.1.min.js:78
(anonymous function)

Comment: As long as you get a js error, swiper will not work correctly. There's something wrong when crating the pagination, but it's hard to make a suggestion without more information. Try to fix this first.